# smooth animate between 3 locations swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, uiviewanimation

still i'm bignner in swift and ios

i'm building my unversity project, but i faced some issues with animating, firstly here is my code:

```
    @IBAction func tab1(_ sender: Any) {
 
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:{
        self.slider.center.x -= self.tab1.bounds.width
    })
}

@IBAction func tab2(_ sender: Any) {
    
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:{
        self.slider.center.x += self.tab2.bounds.width
    })
}
@IBAction func tab3(_ sender: Any) {
       
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:{
        self.slider.center.x += self.tab3.bounds.width
    })
}
```

you can see how much it's basic , and there is many problems like if slider in tab1 and click on tab 3 slider will move one step (to tab2) than user needs press one more time, + if you are in tab2 and press on tab2 again slider move again , many bugs in my code, i search for solutions but no luck .
i want adjust it to be animate to correct place and validate it, that means if slider in correct place the slider will not move.
i hope find some help from swift developers

[image: pointer with tabs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the button frame to calculate x:

```
let tab = sender as! UIView
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:{
    self.slider.center.x = tab.frame.midX
})
```